# Count first occurence with column value ordered by another column

Tags: mysql, select, count

I have an `assigns` table with the following columns:

```
id - int
id_lead - int
id_source - int
date_assigned - int (this represents a unix timestamp)
```

Now, lets say I have the following data in this table:

```
id id_lead id_source date_assigned
1  20      5         1462544612
2  20      6         1462544624
3  22      6         1462544615
4  22      5         1462544626
5  22      7         1462544632
6  25      6         1462544614
7  25      8         1462544621
```

Now, lets say I want to get a count of the rows whose id_source is 6, and is the first entry for each lead (sorted by date_assigned asc).

So in this case, the count would = 2, because there are 2 leads (id_lead 22 and 25) whose first id_source is 6.

How would I write this query so that it is fast and would work fine as a subquery select? I was thinking something like this which doesn't work:

```
select count(*) from `assigns` where `id_source`=6 order by `date_assigned` asc limit 1
```

I have no idea how to write this query in an optimal way. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check my update, I think the simple query is enough for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pseudocode:

```pseudocode
select rows 
with a.id_source = 6
but only if
    there do not exist any row
        with same id_lead
        and smaller date_assigned
```

Translate it to SQL

```sql
select *                                     -- select rows 
from assigns a
where a.id_source = 6                        -- with a.id_source = 6
  and not exists (                           -- but only if there do not exist any row
    select 1
    from assigns a1
    where a1.id_lead = a.id_lead             -- with same id_lead
      and a1.date_assigned < a.date_assigned -- and smaller date_assigned
  )
```

Now replace `select *` with `select count(*)` and you'll get your result.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3dc0f5/7

**Update:**

The NOT-EXIST query can be rewritten to an excluding LEFT JOIN query:

```sql
select count(*)
from assigns a
left join assigns a1
    on  a1.id_lead = a.id_lead
    and a1.date_assigned < a.date_assigned
where a.id_source = 6
  and a1.id_lead is null
```

If you want to get the count for all values of `id_source`, the folowing query might be the fastest:

```sql
select a.id_source, count(1)
from (
    select a1.id_lead, min(a1.date_assigned) date_assigned
    from assigns a1
    group by a1.id_lead
) a1
join assigns a
    on  a.id_lead = a1.id_lead
    and a.date_assigned = a1.date_assigned
group by a.id_source
```

You still can replace `group by a.id_source` with `where a.id_source = 6`.

The queries need indexes on `assigns(id_source)` and `assigns(id_lead, date_assigned)`.

Comment: i wrote a similar query but the problem is that i want this to be within a subquery. a subquery within a subquery is impossible from an optimization standpoint. thanks for your help though.

Comment: @kjdion84, if you have wrote a similar query you should have mentioned that in your question and explain, why it's not a solution. However a (derived) subquery that returns a constant value (in this case "2") should not be problem. If your subquery is going to be correlated (somthing like: `where a.id_source = outer.id_source`), then it might be better to use my last query in a JOIN instead of subquery.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple query for that would be**

check here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8666e0/7

```
select count(*) from 
(select * from assigns group by id_lead )t 
where t.id_source=6
```